# Bootstrap Jumbotron Formatting Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to place an image and two lines of text in a jumbotron. The following code produces near to the desired result:

```
        <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img src="images/ps_logo.png" style="width: 220px; height: 140px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
                <p style="font-size:380%; font-weight: bold; padding-top:10px">Picante Solutions, LLC</p>
            </div>
            <p style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold; font-size:150%">Professional Technology Services for Business and Home</p>
        </div>
```

I get a nice little jumbotron with my image on the left and the two text items on the right. However, when I place the second paragraph tag inside the div with the first one to get the two paragraphs to line up properly, the jumbotron collapses to a thin line above the image and text paragraphs.

I've tried removing the image and all of the inline formatting. Nothing seems to work except for removing the second paragraph element from within the div.

I would appreciate any help you could provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `container` element:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="images/ps_logo.png" style="width: 220px; height: 140px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
      <p style="font-size:380%; font-weight: bold; padding-top:10px">Picante Solutions, LLC</p>
      <p style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold; font-size:150%">Professional Technology Services for Business and Home</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

demo http://www.bootply.com/Vhw5rffz8D

Answer (score 0):

Add clearfix div after two blocks alligned . In your example, just before closing div of Jumbotron. Here is the example :

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
<div class="col-md-1">
    <img src="images/ps_logo.png" style="width: 220px; height: 140px">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
    <p style="font-size:380%; font-weight: bold; padding-top:10px">Picante Solutions, LLC</p>
<p style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold; font-size:150%">Professional Technology Services for Business and Home</p>
</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```